# LU-decomposition of matrices, termination

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that for strictly diagonally dominant matrices, that means matrices for which
$|a_{ii}| > \sum_{j, j \neq i}^n|a_{ji}|, i = 1,..,n $ without pivoting the LU decomposition does not terminate.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by induction, for $n=1$ it is trivial,

\begin{align}
(\tilde{a}_{ij})_{i,j\leq n}&=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
a_{ij} & i=1 \\
a_{ij}-\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}} \cdot a_{1j} & i \neq 1
\end{array}\right.\\
\left| a_{ii}-\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}}\cdot a_{1i}\right|&> \sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^n
\left| a_{ij} -\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}} \cdot a_{1j}\right|\\
\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^n
\left| a_{ij} -\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}} \cdot a_{1j}\right|&\leq
\sum_{j=2,j\neq i}^n |a_{ij}|+\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}}\sum_{j=2,j\neq i}^n |a_{1j}|\\
&< |a_{ii}|-|a_{i1}|+\left| \frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}}\right| (|a_{11}|-|a_{1i}|)\\
&=|a_{ii}|-\left| \frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}}\right|\\
&\leq |\tilde{a}_{ii}|
\end{align}
This proves that the submatrix which you get after the first step of the LU decomposition is still strict diagonal dominant.